# Generically apply context to method aliases

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I an encountering a problem which I can't solve. I don't know whether it is a lack knowledge, or the fact that it is not even possible in Javascript, but I hope to get to know it.

I am trying to execute a list of function aliases in an object. When executing these functions, I would like to use them as if they were executed right from the instance itself, So I can use other methods and instance variables within that called method. To make my explaination a bit more clear, here is an example:

```js
class Bar {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Bar";
  }
    
  someMethod() {
    console.log(this.name) // should log Bar
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Foo";
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    console.log(this.name) // should log Foo
  }
}

const bar = new Bar();
const foo = new Foo();


const methodList = {
  foo: bar.someMethod,
  baz: foo.someOtherMethod,
}

for(let prop in methodList) {
  methodList[prop](); // logs 2x undefined
}

for(let prop in methodList) {
  methodList[prop].apply(foo); //logs 2x Foo
}
```

As can be seen in the example above, `this.name` is a variable in the instance of the class. When executing the second loop, a context is applied and logs correctly, as expected. I would like to see that context being applied automatically, since the function alias object is executed in a different file, not knowing about `foo` or `bar` and just receiving the list.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is because when you invoke `methodList[prop]`, its contextual `this` is `methodList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the contextual `this` when invoking `methodList[prop]`
 is `methodList`, hence `this` in `someMethod` and `someOtherMethod` is actually:

```
{
  foo: bar.someMethod,
  baz: foo.someOtherMethod,
}
```

To solve the issue, you can wrap the methods in an anonymous function returning the invoked method, as shown below:

```js
class Bar {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Bar";
  }
    
  someMethod(a,b,c) {
    console.log(a,b,c,this.name) // should log Bar
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Foo";
  }

  someOtherMethod(a,b,c) {
    console.log(a,b,c,this.name) // should log Foo
  }
}

const bar = new Bar();
const foo = new Foo();


const methodList = {
  foo: (...args) => bar.someMethod(...args), // <-- anonymous function that, once invoked, returns `bar.someMethod()`, hence the contextual `this` of someMethod will be `bar`.
  baz: function() {  // <-- same as above, just written without the lambda notation.
     return foo.someOtherMethod(...arguments);
  }//^
}//  | <-- that evaluation is actually calling the above code block.
//   |-------------------------------------|
for(let prop in methodList) {//            |
  methodList[prop](1,4,'hello'); // <------|
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if I would like to apply arguments to the function alias? Is and how is that possible?

Comment: @EranMachiels just provide the arguments to the callback. For example, if you need to inject an argument to someMethod of bar, you can do: `foo: (arg) => bar.someMethod(arg);` and, on methodList, you should do: `methodList[prop](arg);` Otherwise, just use `...args` on both signatures in methodList, invoking the method with args.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Giving you the solution check because of the clearness of the code due to the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your `foo` and `bar` methods in a function of their own. Within these methods you could then call the object's method `someMethod()`/`someOtherMethod()` on the object like so:

```
const methodList = {
  foo: (...args) => bar.someMethod(...args),
  baz: (...args) => foo.someOtherMethod(...args),
}
```

At the moment your first loop doesn't work because your `this` doesn't refer to the actual context of the object as that isn't what is used to invoke the method. It instead refers to your `methodList`

See example bellow:

```js
class Bar {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Bar";
  }
    
  someMethod() {
    console.log(this.name) // should log Bar
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Foo";
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    console.log(this.name) // should log Foo
  }
}

const bar = new Bar();
const foo = new Foo();


const methodList = {
  foo: (...args) => bar.someMethod(...args),
  baz: (...args) => foo.someOtherMethod(...args),
}

for(let prop in methodList) {
  methodList[prop](); // correct logs
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if I would like to apply arguments to the function alias? Is and how is that possible?

Comment: you can use the rest syntax (`...`). I've updated my answer to use it. This will allow you to accept n arguments which can then be passed into your actual method